# Identify the application developed in DXA or DD4T

Tags: dxa, dd4t

I have application solution which was developed 1 year back now I want to update the application to work with SDL Tridion 8.5
I want to know application was developed in DXA 1.0 or DD4T .

DD4T.ContentModel
DD4T.ContentModel.Contracts
DD4T.ContentModel.XmlSerializers
DD4T.Core.Contracts
DD4T.Factories
DD4T.Serialization
DD4T.Utils
DD4T.ViewModels

I have found above DD4T DLL added as reference in solution but not sure how to make sure it's developed in DXA or DD4T because DXA also use DD4T framework as base.

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not work, as some systems/implementers disable this, but you could try adding ?format=json to your application's URL. If it is based on DXA, you'll get a JSON object with the page data in it.

Comment: And also if you see your application has Areas, as DXA application uses modular approach in its implementation.

Comment: IIRC, the ability to retrieve JSON (or different formats than HTML in general) was introduced in DXA 1.1, so it may not work on an DXA/TRI 1.0 implementation. You can check whether your web app contains `Sdl.Web.Mvc.dll`, though.